Kali Linux and dual boot with Grub2
I double installed windows and kali linux on my pc and now when i try to boot on kali it shows "you need to load the kernel first" how can i fix this problem?

I would suggest that you try installing a more user-friendly Linux distribution and then whatever tools you need for your testing. Kali is designed for professional penetration testing by experienced administrators .
